# Get SUM of column values with multiple rows in Array in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a table with columns and rows.
There are two columns in my table with the names of ID and Digit.
And in my table, some of the rows have the same IDs, and I'm trying to get the SUM of all of the Digit values that there in the rows.

This is part of my code :

```
$ArrayOfStrings = implode(',',$IDs);
$sqls = "SELECT Digit FROM MyTable where ID in ({$ArrayOfStrings })";
```

So how can I get the SUM of all digits, instead every single one?

Answer (score 0):

You just `SUM()`...:

```
$sqls = "select sum(digit) as sum_digit from MyTable where ID in ({$ArrayOfStrings})"
```

Disclaimer: if `$ID` comes from outside of your code to start with, then consider building a parameterized query rather than concatenating the values in the query string.